# Adobe Brackets - debugging Node.js & Node-inspector

Tags: node.js, adobe-brackets

Quick question: Is it possible to use Adobe Brackets to debug Node.js using Node-inspector. Like be able to step debug in Adobe Brackets?

Thanks
Regards
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a Brackets extension for "Live Development" with Node.js:
https://github.com/DennisKehrig/brackets-v8-node-live

And a general JS debugger extension:
https://github.com/jdiehl/brackets-debugger

The problem is they don't work together yet: the debugger assumes you're using the usual Live Development mode, which connects to a Chrome browser instance.  The authors of those two extensions collaborate frequently, and I believe at one point they were working on making the extensions compatible (see the "v8bridge" branch in the first extension). I think they'd be pretty responsive if you start a thread in the *brackets-dev* Google Groups forum with this question.

Comment: There's also https://github.com/TheBenji/brackets-node-debugger but it's no more active than the others.

Answer (score 1):

The [Theseus project for Brackets](http://blog.brackets.io/2013/08/28/theseus-javascript-debugger-for-chrome-and-nodejs/) is an 'omniscient debugger' that supports inspecting code that's running in Node.